# Replace blanks in a column with values based on another column

Tags: powerbi, dax

```
User Id  log in                   log off
user1    12/3/2020 8:12:00am      12/3/2020 11:15:00am
user2    12/3/2020 11:24:00am     12/3/2020 13:30:00pm
user3                             12/3/2020 11:40:00am
user4                             12/3/2020 13:12:00pm
user5    12/3/2020  09:24:00am    12/3/2020 15:44:00pm
```

I have the above data set in Power BI for employees who are remotely logging in and logging off (with their log in time and date). In the `log in` column for `user3` and `user4` column is blank. For `user3` and `user4` in the `log in` column, I want same date according to log off column but time should be `12:00:00am`.

For example, for `user3` in log in column entry in log in column should be `12/3/2020 12:00:00am` and in `log off` it should be as it is (i.e. `12/3/2020 11:40:00am`).

The same should be apply to `user4`. I.e. for `user4` the `log in` entry should be `12/3/2020 12:00:00am` and the `log off` entry should be as it is (i.e. `12/3/2020 13:12:00pm`).

Can anyone suggest to me how to do this in Power BI?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a new calculated column.

```
LogIn =
IF (
    ISBLANK ( 'Table'[log in] ),
    DATEVALUE ( 'Table'[log off] ),
    'Table'[log in]
)
```

This is a good opportunity to use the new [`COALESCE` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/coalesce-function-dax) too:

```
LogIn =
COALESCE (
    'Table'[log in],
    DATEVALUE ( 'Table'[log off] )
)
```